# Strange errors on an SSD drive Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ssd

Getting really weird errors on this drve. Can't figure out where it comes from.

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
Model Number:       KINGSTON SV100S264G                     
Serial Number:      08AAB0016979        
Firmware Revision:  D100811a
Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II 
                    Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
```

Dmesg output

```
[2237481.532836] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[2237481.533053] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[2237481.533414] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[2237481.533867] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[2237481.533867]          res 41/40:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[2237481.534802] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[2237481.535259] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[2237481.536197] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[2237481.536204] ata1: EH complete
[2237481.536658] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[2237481.536890] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[2237481.537240] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[2237481.537692] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[2237481.537693]          res 41/40:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[2237481.538620] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[2237481.539081] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[2237481.540014] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[2237481.540020] ata1: EH complete
[2237481.540476] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[2237481.540712] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[2237481.541057] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[2237481.541513] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[2237481.541513]          res 41/40:00:10:0a:01/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[2237481.542440] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[2237481.542904] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[2237481.543843] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[2237481.543851] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[2237481.543853] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[2237481.543857] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[2237481.543861] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[2237481.543863]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[2237481.543873]         01 01 0a 10 
[2237481.543877] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[2237481.543881] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 01 01 0a 10 00 00 08 00
[2237481.543890] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 16845328
[2237481.544100] ata1: EH complete
```

smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sda

```
Error 463 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1279 hours (53 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 0a 40 e3  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x03400a10 = 54528528

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 f8 10 0a 40 e3 08   1d+16:13:20.504  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]

Error 462 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1279 hours (53 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 0a 40 e3  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x03400a10 = 54528528

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 f8 10 0a 40 e3 08   1d+16:13:20.504  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]

Error 461 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1279 hours (53 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 0a 40 e3  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x03400a10 = 54528528

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 f8 10 0a 40 e3 08   1d+16:13:20.504  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]

Error 460 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1279 hours (53 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 0a 40 e3  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x03400a10 = 54528528

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 f8 10 0a 40 e3 08   1d+16:13:20.504  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]

Error 459 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1279 hours (53 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 0a 40 e3  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x03400a10 = 54528528

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 f8 10 0a 40 e3 08   1d+16:13:20.504  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+16:13:20.504  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
```

Comment: When did you get the SSD? Looks like it's failing

Comment: Like 3 months ago ... kind of 'fresh'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem which now seems to be resolved. Haven't a clue what these errors mean, but this was what happened for me anyway.

Computer Asus +Z99H laptop. Installing Ubuntu 11.04. Had a couple of hundred gigs of video and a Windows XP partition.

I initially installed Ubuntu in a new partition and used this as the partitioning and file transfer OS. Install went smoothly. After transferring data from Windows partition, I then installed Ubuntu into the original Windows partition, intending that this would be the final install.

Part way through the install, I ran my finger along the hinge of the laptop wiping off some dust and accidentally touched the very sensitive power switch, initiating a shutdown.

I restarted the install BUT DID NOT REFORMAT as I did not think it was necessary. Install seemed to go OK but could only start on low graphics mode. Found the above errors.

Reinstalled, this time reformatting the partition and keeping my mitts away from the power switch. Everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Firmware update to the version found at Kingston's website ending in 225a for this model of SSD and voilà ;)